# Zend Framework 2 without Vhost configuration

Tags: zend-framework2, vhosts

I had finished my first web application using Zend Framework 2 and I'm about to put it online.
But may web host doesn't allow me to change my vhost configuration!
The .htaccess file is allowed.

So my question is: How to set up my ZF2 app with only .htaccess files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have a standard ZF2 application based of the skeleton, then try creating a `.htaccess` file in the root with this in it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

I haven't tested this, but in theory, this should effectively move the document root to the public directory while keeping it out of the url.

Comment: What if my web project is located under a folder, like `/var/www/html/myproject` ?