# How can I bypass the .htaccess in a parent directory?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework2, virtualhost

My question is the same as: [Zend Framework 2 without Vhost configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839268/zend-framework-2-without-vhost-configuration) but the solution didn't solve my problem.

I'm getting a customised 404 page.

my project is in a sub-directory, and I believe the .htaccess in the parent directory is stopping it from working.

note: I can't delete that one because there is another project running there

**htdocs/.htaccess:**

```
Options -Indexes
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^transcripts/$ https://spreadsheets.google.com/a/ci4tcm.com/ccc?    key=0AodnCB9Mr1K1dFFmbGhOc3V4RjBvNzZxSE9EZ1dtSnc&hl=en#gid=0 [R,NC]

# ErrorDocument 404 /pages/404.html
# ErrorDocument 500 /pages/404.html
# ErrorDocument 403 /pages/404.html

# RewriteRule ^css(/)?$ / [R]



# RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9.]*)/([A-Za-z0-9.]*)$ /download/$1/$2/ [R]
# RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9.]*)/([A-Za-z0-9.]*)/$ /download.php?test=$2&fol=$1

RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9.]*)$ /download/$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9\+.-\s]*)/([A-Za-z0-9\+.-\s]*)$ /download.php?folder=$1&file=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9.]*)$ /posters/$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^download/([A-Za-z0-9\+.-\s]*)$ /images/wellbeing_posters/pdfs/$1 [L]

AddHandler server-parsed html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.another-domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

# A bunch of redirect 303's here

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**htdocs/booking/** < Zend application here > (solution to other question).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} = ""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

so my question is, how do I bypass the parent directory .htaccess rule when the user wants to enter the physical sub directory with the Zend Application?

Comment: The link to the other question is incorrect. It's pointing to the Ask page.

Comment: What is it that's not working? The parent folder .htaccess rules just enforce `www` in the URL, they won't be causing any issues with the rules in your ZF project.

Comment: @TimFountain I am not allowed to configure virtual directories. And the answer in the link didn't work for me, so I thought it could be the other htaccess that's causing it. I'm getting a customised 404 not found page when trying to access my ZF App.

Comment: A ZF 404 page? If so, it's more likely to be a routing issue.

Comment: @TimFountain not a ZF 404, it's another custom 404 page. See: http://www.ci4tcm.com/c-booking/ which is the root of the ZF app. Just noticed that htdocs/ contains a Wordpress app

Answer (score 0):

Your edited question added a whole load of stuff to the `.htaccess` in the parent folder which changes things somewhat. Assuming you're able to edit that htaccess, the easiest thing to do would be to move the ZF rules into it. Just change any lines that include `public` and add `c-booking` before it. So as an example, the last line would look like:

```
RewriteRule ^c-booking/public/.*$ /c-booking/public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Also be aware that this is a less secure way to host an app. If you have any non-PHP config files, cache files etc. (things that would normally be outside the web root), make sure they aren't viewable through a browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.change the lines after I move them to the other htaccess or do I not need to move them if I change the line? How do I hide those files from the browser? I'd rather not touch that htdocs if I don't have to.

Comment: If you're moving the lines you need to edit them so the paths are correct.

Comment: is there a solution that I don't need to move the lines?